# Performance improvement of 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, paging

In my c++ program executing on ubuntu, I have a large `2D dynamic array` (approx `25948520)` which I access twice during a for loop.
The access to the dynamic array is `random`.
My application is time critical. So, I want to reduce the access time to the 2D array as much as possible.
Is there any way that I can reduce the random access to the dynamic array as it is large. (Each array element stores int, bool, vector of char).
Secondly, I do not have to iterate thorugh the array as I know the exact indices where I have to find the certain value.

Please suggest some alternatives to achieve above task?

Can increasing paging memory will result into better performance?

Comment: so, do you use vector<vector<>>?

Comment: This sort of question is meaningless without an attached benchmark. "I get x stuff per second, how can I get more?" and "This code does x stuff per second, this slightly different code does y stuff per second, why the difference?" are *far* more answerable than this fluff.

Comment: @JerryYYRain I have just single vector of chars.

Comment: Stupid question: rather than trying to increase the performance of random access, have you thought about speeding up the process using a map/reduce technique? Your large dataset might be split into smaller datasets processed in a distributed, parallel way. Not sure if it's feasibile in your case though. Just a hint.

Comment: If the access is truly random, then probably not, because you won't be able to predict future accesses well enough to prefetch them, and there won't be any sensible way to partition into smaller sets, either. In that case, buying CPUs with larger caches might be good, but that obviously has limits. If it's not truly random, though, but just doesn't have high locality of reference, splitting into smaller data sets or prefetching might have some promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array is large and you do random access, you will (roughly) have a cache miss on each access. You cannot avoid that unless you know the location you will access next before you access it. If you do, you can try to prefetch the location using, e.g., the SSE prefetch intrinsic (`void _mm_prefetch (char const* p, int i)`).

What you can try is allocating your array on huge pages. This will reduce the preasure on your TLB resulting in less TLB misses. Huge page allocation support, however, is OS dependent. If you are using linux, you can read how to allocate an array using huge pages here:http://linuxgazette.net/155/krishnakumar.html

Comment: Can you please provide an example how to allocate array to large pages?

Comment: @Zara: Added a link to a tutorial. However, all the huge page stuff is OS dependent.